# How to in-place edit boolean value with x-editable

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, twitter-bootstrap-3, x-editable

I want to display a boolean value on a page (actually it'll be cells in a table), and it has to be editable. Furthermore, it's not a checkbox, but I spell out "false" and "true". We use bootstrap 3, and latest knockout. I decided to use x-editable Bootstrap 3 build. I also use a knockout custom binding: https://github.com/brianchance/knockout-x-editable.

I figured that to implement this I need to configure x-editable to be in popup mode, and select type. I also supply the selections ("true" and "false" only in this case) in a parameter. Almost everything is fine and dandy, except that the in-place dialog doesn't display the current value when it pops up. How can I fix that? I tried 'defaultValue' parameter, but it didn't help.

Here is the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/csabatoth/7ybVh/4/

```
<span data-bind="editable: value,
      editableOptions: { mode: 'popup', type: 'select',
      source: '[{ value: 0, text: &#34;false&#34; },
                { value: 1, text: &#34;true&#34; }]' }">
</span>
```

simple model:

```
function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.value = ko.observable(false);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you have `true` and `false` Boolean values in your observable but x-editable uses the `0` and `1` values to represent the "true" and "false" selection.

This causes two problems:

- when initialized x-editable does not know that "false" means 0 so no default value selected
- if you select anything in your pop-up editor your `value` observable will contain the "0" and "1" strings and not the `false` and `true` Boolean values...

You can solve both problems with intoroducing a computed property which translates between the Boolean and numerical values:

```
self.computed = ko.computed({
    read: function() { return self.value() ? 1 : 0 },
    write: function(newValue) { self.value(newValue == '1') }
});
```

And you need to use this property in your `editable` binding:

```
<span data-bind="editable: computed,
      editableOptions: { mode: 'popup', type: 'select',
      source: '[{ value: 0, text: &#34;false&#34; },
                { value: 1, text: &#34;true&#34; }]' }">
</span>
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VQcCU/).